# How to print from ionic capacitor / vuejs project

Tags: android, vue.js, ionic-framework, printing, capacitor

I have a project, built with VueJS. Packing it using ionic capacitor as native android app went smoothly. However printing turned out to be problematic.

I cannot find a single example how to do use the native printer plugin https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/printer in a vuejs project.

Comment: What did you try to make the plugin work?

Comment: Struggling to get it working - I installed the plugin, but even the example results in error "Cannot find name 'constructor'". Moreover what I see on the link above looks like something for cordova/angular, not vue/capacitor.

Comment: @nsimeonov did you found an answer?

Comment: @user1670816, nope. I scrapped ionic completely and wrote my own wrapper using Xamarin and WebView - turned out to be easier, than struggling to find out how to do that using ionic, what plugins are compatible and what not - just not my cup of tea apparently